# Why IIS Express is ignoring network route in routing table?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

We have a REST API which is working with Azure CosmosDB. This Azure CosmosDB account has enabled firewall, which allowing traffic from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP address(which is our OpenVPN server).

On client/developer's side we have OpenVPN client which is pushing route to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx CosmosDB via VPN interface. When we build and run this REST API app in Visual Studio via IIS Express, the app is ignoring network route to CosmosDB and even ignoring changes in ..\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file(we have internal VNET ip conigured on that CosmosDB account).

Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: $someActivityId; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["Request originated from IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy through public internet. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-forbidden"]}

But if we run same app in IIS Server(in our case its a IIS 10) network route and hosts file change also working fine. Also network routing works when we using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer or powershell az module. It's not working only when the app is hosted by IIS Express.

Its only working via VPN, if VPN is set as default gateway. In our case we don't want to use VPN as gateway for all traffic.

Does IIS Express has any restrictions which may cause this? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Try to remove the vnet from the firewall rules and readd the same vnet via the portal. Maybe because of some configuration or rule conflict, can you get its error log?

Comment: @Chen
The issue is not with Azure CosmosDB firewall, as its all working fine when VPN server is set as default gateway. The problem is that API which is started in IIS Express is ignoring hosts file and route in routing table. 
The error which i POSTed earlier indicates that request was done via my public IP address.